# Retornar vetor de inteiros em java

Tags: java, array, método, return

Estou tentando ler um vetor de inteiros e retornar a quantidade de uns e a quantidade de zeros, porém ele sempre retorna no mínimo um número zero, mesmo sem eu ter entrado com esse valor. Depurando o código, mesmo na hora da leitura, se eu entrar com 5 vezes o número "um" ele só mostra como preenchido com o número um a primeira casa, e ainda sim, conta quatro. A mesma coisa para a depuração no método *contUm*. 
Gostaria de saber se meu erro está na função que faz a leitura ou na função que conta, grato.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //importa classe scanner para fazer a leitura do teclado

/**
 * link : https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1329
 * @author pmargreff
 */
class Main {

    //método para ler o vetor
    public static int[] leVetor(int tamanho) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] vetor = new int[tamanho];
        for (int i : vetor) {
            vetor[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }

        return vetor;
    }

    public static int contZero(int[] vetor) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i: vetor){
            if (vetor[i] == 0)
                total++;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static int contUm(int[] vetor) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i: vetor){
            if (vetor[i] == 1)
                total++;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); //inicializa teclado como leitura padrão para entrada
        int tamanho = 1; // váriavel que conterá o tamanho total do vetor
        int vetor[]; //vetor onde irá ficar armazenado os resultados da jogada
        int zero, um; //contém o número de vitória referente a cada um

        while (tamanho != 0) {

            tamanho = teclado.nextInt(); //le o tamanho do vetor

            if (tamanho > 0) {
                vetor = new int[tamanho];   //inicializa variáveis com o espaço necessário na memória 
                vetor = leVetor(tamanho); //le o vetor e salve nele próprio
                zero = contZero(vetor);
                um = contUm(vetor);
                System.out.println("Zeros: " + zero);
                System.out.println("Uns: " + um);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na maneira como você altera o array. Veja:

```
for (int i : vetor) {
   vetor[i] = teclado.nextInt();
}
```

O código acima está obtendo cada valor no array e depois usando este valor como índice. Acontece que índice do array é uma coisa e o valor naquele índice é outra. Você acabou de inicializar o array com X inteiros. Cada inteiro (*int*) foi inicializado pelo Java com o valor zero. Entao no seu primeiro loop, você está setando X vezes o valor no índice zero, cada novo valor sobrescreve o anterior, sempre no índice zero.

Experimente percorrer seus arrays ("vetores") assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    vetor[i] = teclado.nextInt();
}
```

No código acima o valor de **i** é incrementado a cada iteração no loop e até o último elemento no array; e então **i** é usado como índice para alterar os elementos deste mesmo array.

Comment: Olá, resolvi dessa forma, estava usando for (int i : vetor) por ter lido n em um artigo, sobre as novas funções a partir do java 1.5(se não me engano), e pelo que eu tinha entendido essa forma de ler o vetor percorreria o mesmo do inicio ao fim. Devo ter sido falho ao interpretar a documentação. Grato, desculpe o equívoco.

Comment: @pmargreff O loop **for** que você usava não estava errado - é válido e útil percorrer uma coleção assim. O problema era que você usava o **valor** do item como se ele fosse o **índice** do item na coleção. Tentei deixar isso mais claro na minha resposta.